# Putting a #endif inside a #if

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to put a #endif inside a #if as the block's 'content' not as the pair #endif for the #if?

```
#if (SOME_CONDITION)
    #if (ANOTHER_CONDITION)
#endif // pair endif for #if (SOME_CONDITION)


#if (SOME_CONDITION)
    #endif // pair endif for #if (ANOTHER_CONDITION)
#endif // pair endif for #if (SOME_CONDITION)
```

If this is not possible how to conditionally compile a #if ... #endif pair?

This is what I was doing.

I was modifying a code base that we bought from another company. To compile it with and without my modifications easily I was using a macro say like shown below.

```
#if (MY_COMPANY_EDITS_ENABLED)
// My Modified code goes here
#else
// unmodified code from another company
#endif
```

In this way I could easily compile in/out my modifications while maintaining readability about my edits. I was using the same #if #else #endif blocks everywhere. But then I came across a code that is being compiled in, in the original unmodified code base, based on some macro value.

```
#if (FEATURE_A_IS_ENABLED)
// Line 1
// Line 2
#endif
```

But I want to compile this code [Line 1 and Line 2] regardless of the macro value FEATURE_A_IS_ENABLED

My first thought was to follow the same convention that I used till now [to maintain readability about my edits].

```
#if (MY_COMPANY_EDITS_ENABLED)
//#if (FEATURE_A_IS_ENABLED)
#else
#if (FEATURE_A_IS_ENABLED)
#endif

// Line 1
// Line 2

#if (MY_COMPANY_EDITS_ENABLED)
// #endif
#else
#endif
#endif
```

Then I realized this is not possible.

I know, alternative methods exist to achieve the same. But was wondering whether I could use the same convention

```
#if (MY_COMPANY_EDITS_ENABLED)
// My Modified code goes here
#else
// unmodified code from another company
#endif
```

in this case too.

Comment: What does it mean? Which if is it ending?

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. I will update the question.

Comment: Sorry for being honest, that doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @NeonGlow That's simply not possible. How is the preprocessor supposed to know which `#if` goes with which `#endif`?! You could probably solve it using good old boolean logic instead.

Comment: @iharob : I know this is  absurd, but just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Biffen : I was wondering whether there is any such option to specify the pair to the preprocessor

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, as the preprocessor only does a single pass over your file, and the `#endif` gets matched with the preceding `#if`. If you want to make an `#if`/`#endif` block conditional, then just nest it inside another `#if`/`#endif` block:

```
#if CONDITION_A
#  if CONDITION_B
...
#  endif /* CONDITION_B */
#endif /* CONDITION_A */
```

Put another way, it's not possible to have preprocessing directives construct other preprocessing directives, as the output from the initial "construction" phase will not be reparsed by the preprocessor.

The (silly) example below wouldn't work either for example, even assuming the newlines wouldn't be an issue (which they would be here):

```
#if DEFINE_X_TO_FIVE
#define X
#endif
#if DEFINE_X_TO_FIVE
5
#endif
```

Comment: This is not possible and it's not because of the preprocessor.

Comment: @iharob: Please clarify. It is because of how the preprocessor works.

Comment: Can you do it in any programming langauge at all? I mean conditionally ending an `if` block? suppose that you are the compiler what would you do about it?

Comment: @iharob: It would be possible in macro processors that can do multiple passes over the input. I haven't actually confirmed this, but I believe `m2` can for example. `make` isn't a macro processor, but also has the option of going over the input multiple times with `$$`-style expansions.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The first `#endif` will be matched with the most recent `#if` or `#else`, so your code will be interpreted like this:

```
#if (SOME_CONDITION)
    #if (ANOTHER_CONDITION)
    #endif // pair endif for #if (ANOTHER_CONDITION)


    #if (SOME_CONDITION)
    #endif // pair endif for the second #if (SOME_CONDITION)
#endif // pair endif for the first #if (SOME_CONDITION)
```

Comment: Exactly, that's why *it's not possible*, although you see what the OP wants from the indentation.

Comment: Both C language and standard C preprocessor ignore indentation. And for me the indentation doesn't explain OP's intentions, either.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making the changes based on feature sets rather than whether or not they are yours or not then group them together to make a given version (MY_COMPANY_EDITS_ENABLED) or whatever:

```
#if (MY_COMPANY_EDITS_ENABLED)
     #define FEATUREA
     #define FEATUREB
     #define FEATUREC
     #define FEATURED
#else
     #define FEATUREA
     #undef  FEATUREB
     #undef  FEATUREC
     #undef  FEATURED
#endif

#ifdef FEATUREA
//do some feature A stuff
#endif

// do code

#ifdef FEATUREB
//do some feature B stuff
#endif

#ifndef FEATUREC
//do some stuff if not feature C
#endif

// etc...
```

This is a lot more flexible in the long run and lets you switch changes features on and off with a rebuild.

Answer (score -2):

Off course you can nest your preprocessor directives:

```
#ifdef CONDITION1
// some code here
      # ifdef CONDITION2
      // some else here
      # endif
#endif
```

But make sure to end each condition properly.

See also: http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#1995_vanschnitz and http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#2004_vik2

Comment: See also C11: 6.10.1 p4